# How to distinguish between newly granted permissions and permissions copied after removing inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, powershell, permissions, acl

I found the following script and it helps me alot.
This Script creating a CSV file with the permissions of every user from the given rootpath.
If child items of this path have permission changes the script create an record too.
Unfortunately I don’t know how to differentiate an inheritance break und new rights of a user or an group. Both records in the CSV file look the same.

```
function Get-PathPermissions {
  param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.String]${Path} )

  begin {
    $root = Get-Item $Path
    ($root | get-acl).Access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $($root.fullname).ToString() -PassThru
  }

  process {
    $containers = Get-ChildItem -path $Path -recurse | ? {$_.psIscontainer -eq $true}
    if ($containers -eq $null) {break}
    foreach ($container in $containers)
    {
      (Get-ACL $container.fullname).Access | ? { $_.IsInherited -eq $false } | Add- ember -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $($container.fullname).ToString() -PassThru
    }
  }
}

Get-PathPermissions $arg[0] | Export-Csv $outputFileName -Delimiter ";"
```

Does anybody know how to fix my problem?

Comment: i think you will have to compare the access value of the "not inherited" folder with it's parent ...

Comment: @Kayasax is correct. There's not technical difference between ACEs added when removing inheritance and manually added ACEs.